# RabbitMq bindings

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I realize I may be doing it wrong - but here's your chance to correct me!

I have a device - with id of say... 60.
Device 60 is processed by Master 2.

I receive a message from the device and in the message header is its id. But at this stage my program doesnt know, or care which master the device is assigned.

I want to put all messages for device 60 into a RabbitMq Queue called "Device60" At this point nothing may be listening to that queue. Which is why I cant use an exchange b/c if nothing is listening then the message would just be dropped. I need the messages to stay in Queue60 until they are processed.

When Master 2 comes on line its has a list of say 600 devices it will process for. So it at that point it could create bindings.

How can I do a Queue to Queue binding to distribute the messages in "Device60" to the "Master2" queue?

If I am approaching this all wrong please help me understand the 'correct' way based upon the RabbitMq implementation of AMQP

Requirements are any device can send in a message(s) and they will be saved, in order, until something comes online and pulls them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the routing key(s), by creating an exchange and a queue called `Device60` bound to the exchange.

```
channel.queueBind("Device60","myexchange","device.60")
```

At this point you can publish the message,using the routing key.
For example:

```
 channel.basicPublish("myexchange","device.60",mymessage);
```

now the `Device60` will receive the messages and store them until the consumer is online.

For the other devices it is the same:

```
channel.queueBind("Device50","myexchange","device.50")
```

and

```
channel.basicPublish("myexchange","device.50",mymessage);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. My consumer will come online and establish a queue 'Master.2' - how can it then receive messages for any device for which it is responsible? Sorry if I wasnt clear in my question. So it will bind the device60 exchange to Master.2 queue, but what about the pre-existing messages in the Device60 queue?

Comment: you can create another queue and bind it using the routing key #. as `channel.queueBind("Master.2","myexchange","device.#") `. Hope I got your point :)!

Comment: And that would then route all existing messages ? My understanding was that it would only route new messages.

Comment: Yes, you are right.Another way is to use the shovel plug-in and copy the message across the queues through binding rules.

Comment: So I do the queueBind - then I perform the shovel - what order are the messages in now assuming messages are still flowing in while I perform the shovel? Would I need to take an extra step to ensure I get them in the correct order? - Thank you so much for the info btw.

Comment: Wait I think I got it - createQueue - perform shovel - bindQueue to exchange. That would ensure the order isnt messed up

Comment: This seems like a case where a Queue - to - Queue binding would make life so much easier.

Comment: yes, seems a bit complex in this way, but if works ok. Btw let me know. I usually try to implement easy design :)!

Comment: It just seems like a good feature request. A queue that behaves like a queue when nothing is bound, but behaves like an exchange when something is bound.